# The command is not visible in my eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development. Recently, I downloaded a completed source code of an Eclipse plugin from another team. The popup menu of the plugin is not visible,  so I just created a simple popup-menu-command for testing.

In the project, I only changed the plugin.xml to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            description="some description"
            id="com.something.aCommand"
            name="somet name">
      </command>
      </extension>

    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
            <command commandId="com.something.aCommand"
                label="Create HTML" style="push">
            </command>
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>

<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="com.something.aHandler"
            commandId="com.something.aCommand">
      </handler>
      </extension>
</plugin>
```

(The aCommand and aHandler are nicknames of the real command and handler which do exist)

This sample is similar to the example here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#extending-the-eclipse-ide

And I tested it by Run as-> Eclipse Appliication, the right-click-pupup-command "Create HTML" is not visible.

Besides, this project does not contain fragment.e4mi file, does this mean it is a Eclipse 3 plug-in ? Because I find almost all eclipse plug-in tutorials are using fragment.e4mi and the e4 model fragment UI.

Environment:

- Windows 10 64-bits
- Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Comment: This is using the Eclipse 3 style menus, but these still work fine in Eclipse 4 for RCPs using 3.x compatibility mode (Eclipse itself is such an RCP).

Comment: Your command is defined with `acommand` in lower case, but the references are in mixed case `aCommand`

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your reply! But it is just a misspelling.  I am modifying it.

Comment: @greg-449 May I ask how to use 3.x compatibility mode? I am adding my working environment in the question.

Comment: ok, just be convenient for others. I find the explanation of  3.x compatibility model here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html#running-eclipse-3-x-plug-ins-on-top-of-eclipse-4

Comment: If you are just running a plugin in Eclipse you are using 3,x compatibility mode. You only use e4 mode if you create a new product using that,

Comment: @greg-449 Yeah, I am not going to create one product. I will just use the existing one. But the popup-menu-command "Create HTML" is not visible, may I ask any thing I need look into?

Comment: This looks OK to me. You are looking at Package Explorer (not Project Explorer) since you are only adding to the package explorer menu?

Comment: @greg-449 You are right! I mixed the Project explorer and Package explorer!  I should use "locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu" instead.  You can add this as an answer , I will mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically OK but is only contributing to the Package Explorer view (id `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer`)

For Project Explorer to context menu id is `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu`.

You can also use `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any` to contribute to any menu.